# Rails: FakeModel runs the same validation too many times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

We have created a FakeModel object class which inherits from Object,
to allow working with models who don't have a DB table.

It has the basic functionality of a regular ActiveRecord model.
We also added in the class the following line:

```
include ActiveRecord::Validations
```

The problem is this:
A new request is sent to the controller, and creates a new object inheriting from the FakeModel class.
When the validations of that object run, they run more then once.
Too be more specific - with each request sent to the server,
the validations run one time more than the last request.

I'm guessing something here "sticks" on the server-level
(of course, when I restart the server, it resets back to running the validations just once)

What can be the cause of that?

**UPDATE :**

The ActiveModel solution isn't possible for me because I'm using Rails 2.3.8. I still need to figure out where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ActiveModel instead of writing your own Model engine from scratch, see [this blog post for a tutorial](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) you can also watch [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model)

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't supported in versions prior to Rails 3.

Comment: You're right, you might update your post to tell us which rails version you are using.

Comment: I think that people believe the question has been answered.
How can I emphasize the fact that it hasn't..?

Comment: I just edit your post to make it clear the ActiveModel isn't a solution for you, it should help but we will have to wait for my edit accepted.

Comment: [This post](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/rails/validations-in-any-class/) may help you about adding validation to your model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stabbing the dark here, but it sounds like the validations keep being included every time the model is loaded/saved.

Can you show us where you include it?

In Hyperactive Resource, instead of include we used:

```
# make validations work just like ActiveRecord by pulling them in directly
require "active_record/validations.rb"
extend ActiveRecord::Validations::ClassMethods
```